# How do I remove the window borders from modal dialogs in Cinnamon?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, window, cinnamon, dialog

System: Ubuntu 13.04, with Cinnamon 1.8.

Whenever a modal dialog like the one below (password prompt in GDebi) pops up, it always has an annoying border around it. Is there any way to fix this?

I should mention that I installed GNOME Shell beforehand, but have since removed it.

[image: Oh look. Borders.]

Comment: I've refunded your bounty since you seem to be encountering a problem that is caused by some misconfiguration on your system. What window manager are you using with Cinnamon?

Comment: that's ok. Perhaps it would also be useful when we knew what window manager theme he is using!

Comment: I assume I'm using Muffin as my window manager. It does look like a weird misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed gdebi and I've tried to reproduce your error.
But without success as you can see in the screenshot.
Can you tell me what cinnamon theme you have used?
Are you using 2d fallback or 3d??

[image]

That's the modal dialog section of my cinnamon theme:

```
 /* ===================================================================
 * Modal dialogs
 * ===================================================================*/
.show-processes-dialog-subject,
.mount-question-dialog-subject,
.end-session-dialog-subject {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.modal-dialog {
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    background-gradient-direction: vertical;
    background-gradient-start: rgba(32,32,32,1.0);
    background-gradient-end: rgba(32,32,32,1.0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;

    padding: 30px 42px;
}

.modal-dialog-button-box {
    spacing: 21px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.modal-dialog-button {
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 4px 32px 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgba(78,78,78,0.9);
    background-gradient-direction: vertical;
    background-gradient-start: rgba(58,58,58,1.0);
    background-gradient-end: rgba(32,32,32,1.0);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.modal-dialog-button:active,
.modal-dialog-button:pressed {
    border-color: rgba(98,98,98,0.4);
    background-gradient-direction: vertical;
    background-gradient-start: rgba(28,28,28,1.0);
    background-gradient-end: rgba(32,32,32,1.0);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

.modal-dialog-button:active:hover,
.modal-dialog-button:pressed:hover {
    border-color: rgba(98,98,98,0.4);
    background-gradient-direction: vertical;
    background-gradient-start: rgba(28,28,28,1.0);
    background-gradient-end: rgba(32,32,32,1.0);
}

.modal-dialog-button:hover {
    border-color: rgba(98,98,98,0.9);
    background-gradient-direction: vertical;
    background-gradient-start: rgba(68,68,68,1.0);
    background-gradient-end: rgba(58,58,58,1.0);
}

.modal-dialog-button:disabled {
    color: rgb(60,60,60);
}

.modal-dialog-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(117,145,169,0.9);
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this now. Thanks for your reply, I'll also test my other themes.